# How do I login multiple users with Devise in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, devise

In my spec, I have this `before :each`:

```
  before :each do
    @user1 = create(:user, gender: 0)
    @user2 = create(:user)
    @membership1 = create(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user1.family_tree, inviter: @user1, invited: @user2, relation: "sister", relative_type: 1)
    @membership2 = create(:membership, member: nil, family_tree: @user2.family_tree, inviter: @user2, invited: @user1, relation: "brother", relative_type: 1)
    @connection = create(:connection, inviter_membership: @membership1, invited_membership: @membership2, inviter_user: @user1, invited_user: @user2, request_status: 1)
    sign_in @user1
  end
```

I then have this test that is failing:

```
  it "should NOT delete the inviter_membership record" do
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: @user1
    }.not_to change(Membership,:count)
  end
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError: expected #count not to have changed, but did change from 2 to 1
```

However, once I do this: `sign_in @user2`, that test passes. But because I am no longer signing in `@user1` other tests fail. I am not sure how to sign_in both users at the same time.

What's the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I figured it out.

All I have to do is leave the `sign_in @user1` in the `before :each` and then in the individual test, I just `sign_in @user2`.

So that test now looks like this:

```
  it "should NOT delete the inviter_membership record" do
    sign_in @user2
    expect {
      delete :destroy, id: @user1
    }.not_to change(Membership,:count)
  end
```

I still don't understand why in this case it requires the 2nd user to be logged in....but at least it no longer fails.

Perhaps there is some validation that was failing on the destroy or update or something.